# Close popup window when successful

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, popup, richfaces

I use a rich:popupPanel component, which displays the input fields for the login. I need to close the popup when the login was successful, but just then. When the user types in a wrong password, I display a message and the popup panel should rest open. If I make a page reload, all welcome messages and other stuff will disappear.

I've got a javascript which closes my popup: `onclick="RichFaces.$('popup_login').hide()"`

How can I run the script only when the action method returns "1" (e.g.) ?

```
<h:form id="loginForm">
   <h:inputText id="email" value="#{loginBean.email}" />
   <a4j:commandLink id="submit" action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" onclick="RichFaces.$('popup_login').hide()">
      <h:outputText value="login" />
   </a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in the `oncomplete` if [validation has not failed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29).

```
<a4j:commandLink ... oncomplete="if (#{!facesContext.validationFailed}) RichFaces.$('popup_login').hide()">
```

Answer (score -1):

i work on primeface. I close all my popup directly from the managedbean.

```
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("idofpopup.hide()");
```

I don't know if this work with Rich.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Those component libraries are not interchangeable.